# Convert the input Strings into a Series

Tags: java, string

In the following program, i am trying to check if the consecutive strings in the `input` array are in a sequence and if so they should be represented as a range as you can see below.
I am able to convert two consecutive strings as a range but i can't figure out how to check and convert more than two consecutive strings in a range.

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    String input = "abc0001, abc0002, abc002, efg00113, efg00114, efg00115, rtasdf1";
    String[] result = input.split(", ");
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length - 1; ++i){
        String[] first = result[i].split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
        int digits1 = Integer.parseInt(first[1]);
        String[] second = result[i + 1].split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
        int digits2 = Integer.parseInt(second[1]);
        if(second[0].equals(first[0]) && (second[1].length() == first[1].length()) && ((digits2 - digits1) == 1)) {
            result[i] = result[i] + "-" + result[i + 1];
            output.add(result[i]);
            ++i;
        }
        else {
            output.add(result[i]);
        }
    }
    String [] out = output.toArray(new String[output.size()]);
    for(String a : out)
        System.out.println(a);

    //Arrays.sort(result);
    //for(String a : result)
    //    System.out.println(a);

    }
    }
```

Output :

```
    Hello World                                                                                                                                           
    abc0001-abc0002                                                                                                                                           
    abc002                                                                                                                                                    
    efg00113-efg00114                                                                                                                                        
    efg00115
```

The last output should be `efg00113-efg00115` instead of `efg00113-efg00114` and `efg00115` separately.

Comment: Why is `abc002` appearing in isolation in your expected results?  Shouldn't it be part of a range?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `abc002` and `abc0002` are not the same and that is why it is not part of the range because for `abc002` to be part of the range, the previous string must be `abc001`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this. I marked places in your code that I changed. The idea is to remember how many consecutive strings we have to convert and do it once we found a string that doesn't match.

**EDIT:** with suggested edit from @daljindersingh

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld{
public static void main( String[] args){
System.out.println( "Hello World");
String input = "test2, abc0001, abc0002, abc002, efg00113, efg00114, efg00115, rtasdf1, test123";
String[] result = input.split( ", ");
List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
int toMerge = 0; // <------>
for( int i = 0; i < result.length; ++i){ // <----------
    if( i == result.length - 1){
        if( toMerge != 0){
            result[ i] = result[ i - toMerge] + "-" + result[ i];
            output.add( result[ i]);
            toMerge = 0;
        }
        else{
            output.add( result[ i]);
        }
        break;
    } // ----------->
    String[] first = result[ i].split( "(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
    int digits1 = Integer.parseInt( first[ 1]);
    String[] second = result[ i + 1].split( "(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
    int digits2 = Integer.parseInt( second[ 1]);
    if( second[ 0].equals( first[ 0]) && (second[ 1].length() == first[ 1].length()) && ((digits2 - digits1) == 1)){
        toMerge++; // <--------
    }
    else{
        if( toMerge != 0){
            result[ i] = result[ i - toMerge] + "-" + result[ i];
            output.add( result[ i]);
            toMerge = 0;
        }
        else{
            output.add( result[ i]); // --------->
        }
    }
}
    String[] out = output.toArray( new String[ output.size()]);
    for( String a : out)
        System.out.println( a);

    // Arrays.sort(result);
    // for(String a : result)
    // System.out.println(a);

}
}
```

Comment: hey, just one issue with this code, the last string in the `input` array is not getting added to `output` ArrayList. How can this be solved.

Comment: @daljindersingh Check the new version. I changed the range of loop and added new part for the last element.

Comment: thanks for the help buddy, just wanna point out a correction in code if you could correct it for others, in the last `if` block, two lines are not required and they actually will not give a correct result in case their are two ranges consecutively, the lines to be removed are `output.add[result[i+1]);` and `i++;`.

Answer (score 1):

You had a few errors in the code, specifically running 2 indexes in some runs which prevented you from adding a third to the sequence - and only allowed you to check pairs. Look at the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    String input = "abc0001, abc0002, abc002, efg00113, efg00114, efg00115, rtasdf1";
    String[] result = input.split(", ");
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length - 1; ++i){
        String[] first = result[i].split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
        int digits1 = Integer.parseInt(first[1]);
        String[] second = result[i + 1].split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
        int digits2 = Integer.parseInt(second[1]);
        if(second[0].equals(first[0]) && (second[1].length() == first[1].length()) && ((digits2 - digits1) == 1)) {
            //Check if previous sequence contains the current. If so, replace
            if (!output.isEmpty() && output.get(output.size()-1).indexOf(result[i])>=0) {
              String startSequence = output.get(output.size()-1);
              if (startSequence.indexOf("-")>=0) {
                startSequence = startSequence.substring(0,startSequence.indexOf("-"));
              }

              output.remove(output.size()-1);
              result[i] = startSequence + "-" + result[i + 1];
            } else {
              result[i] = result[i] + "-" + result[i + 1];
            }
            output.add(result[i]);
        }
        else if (i>0) {
          output.add(result[i+1]);
        } else {
          output.add(result[i]);
        }
    }
    String [] out = output.toArray(new String[output.size()]);
    for(String a : out)
        System.out.println(a);

  }
```

Output:

```
Hello World
abc0001-abc0002
abc002
efg00113-efg00115 
rtasdf1
```

Comment: your answer is correct but not for one condition, if the first string in the `input` array is not part of a sequence, it is not getting added to the `output` ArrayList.

Comment: You're right. I corrected the example to catch this end case: 
  else if (i>0) {
            output.add(result[i+1]);
        } else {
          output.add(result[i]);
        }

If you think my answer helped, may I kindly ask you accept it?